# Zoom fails to Time Profile

Tags: linux, zooming

I'm using the Zoom profiler from rotateright.com. It's worked well up until a couple days ago. Now, when I begin profiling (using the "Time Profile" configuration) it shows an error "Failed to start profiling".
Has anyone seen this and/or know how to fix it?

Environment is x86_64 RHEL6. The machine was recently re-located physically, although it seems that shouldn't matter.

Edit: Zoom version is 3.3.3, the latest.

Comment: Is there any other error code/status code than just `Failed to start profiling` ?

Comment: That is the only error information.